# How to set button%'s background in Racket?

Tags: racket

I add a `button%` to a `dialog%` like below:

```
(new button%
  [label "ok"]
  [parent pop-dialog%]
  [callback
    (lambda (b e)
    (exit))])
```

Sorry, my complete code is below:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/gui)

(define *my-frame* (new frame% 
                      [label "VersionMonitor"]
                      [width 300]
                      [height 200]
                      ))

(define pop-dialog 
  (new dialog% 
       [label "bogga wogga"] 
       [parent *my-frame*]
       [width 200]
       [height 100]
       ))

(new canvas%
     [parent pop-dialog]
     [paint-callback
      (lambda (canvas info-dc)
        (send info-dc clear)
        (send info-dc set-background "white"))])

(new button%
  [label "ok"]
  [parent pop-dialog]
  [callback
    (lambda (b e)
    (exit))])

(send *my-frame* show #t)

(send pop-dialog show #t)
```

And now you can see the gray area. My real problem is how to set button%'s area's background
?

But the `button%` has a rectangle around it, beyond itself. The background is gray, I want
set its color to white, but didn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem you're reporting. In particular, I'm running this program:

```
#lang racket

(require mred)

(define pop-dialog 
  (new dialog% [label "bogga wogga"]))

(new button%
  [label "ok"]
  [parent pop-dialog]
  [callback
    (lambda (b e)
    (exit))])

(send pop-dialog show #t)
```

... and I don't see a rectangle around the button. I don't think I can attach a screenshot in ...
oh, wait, maybe I can:

[image: small dialog with one button]

If this doesn't match what you're seeing, see if you can create a small program that illustrates the problem.

Also, the racket mailing list is probably going to give you prompt-er responses, for issues like this.